# Comparing time series of small N group of individuals but reasonably lengthy time series

Tags: time-series, panel-data, small-sample, time-varying-covariate

I have been given some data about pre and post release behavior of a small group of rehabilitated animals in Africa, with some measures of success being how much food the animals eat in the wild and how long they survive after release. There is only data for 8 animals, of which about half 'failed' either by dying or by being brought back to the sanctuary. **What are some standard methods that might yield some informative but not misleading conclusions?**

For each animal I have 1-2 years of data, taken every 30 minutes on the animal during daylight hours, so quite a few time series points per animal, just not many animals. I'm inclined to stick with more exploratory and visualization based methods to get some idea of whether we have any idea what predicts success for these animals, but I'd love some suggestions from folks who are used to dealing with this sort of data and can warn me about pitfalls.

A successful use of this data would be to determine whether some observable features of an animal's behavior before release in any way predict that animal's success after release. We have about 15 different components of the animal's behavior that have been measured. I am guessing several of these components will be highly correlated with one another, so there's that to account for.

The findings can potentially affect which animals are next released from rehabilitation, which is why it's important to avoid drawing incorrect conclusions.

Comment: What is it you want to be able to say from these data?

Comment: @gung thanks for reading my post. I added some detail at the end.